# Is there Widow Orphan protection using Prawn for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn, orphan

I have a question about using Prawn for Ruby on Rails.

I'm using a bounding_box for variable length content.  When the
content overflows to the next page I would like to have some sort of
widow/orphan protection in place.  Is there a recommended solution for
this?

Is there a way to break the content from the previous page at the last
paragraph break, then carry that paragraph to the next page?

Or perhaps take the last x lines from the previous page so that there
are at least x+1 number of lines in the new page?

Thoughts?
Suggestions?

Comment: anyone? is there a way to accomplish something similar to CSS page-break properties?